# CSS button use of .hover for different buttons

Tags: css

This is the top part:

```
button {
    background-color: gray;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 1%;
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 1px 0;
    font-size: 16;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px 0px #333333;
}
.blue-btn {
    background-color: #337AB7;
}
.green-btn {
    background-color: #008000;
}
.red-btn {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Here comes my problem…..

```
.button:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

This one only work if the class is button (it does not work for blue/green/red buttons)
So I tried this instead

```
.button:hover, blue-btn:hover, green-btn:hover, red-btn:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Still only works for button class 
So I tried this one

```
.blue-btn:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.green-btn:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.red-btn:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

That worked – but it seem to me its a bit stupid to write the same bit again and again and again……

Anyone got a tip?

Comment: Did you try `button:hover` instead of `.button:hover`?

Comment: Argh hahaha - totally didnt see that "."  :-D
Works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `button:hover` instead of `.button:hover` .

Comment: Yep woops :-D    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're confusing element names with classes. A button is an actual element (`<button></button>`) and `.button` is a class you've created.

I don't know if what you have is a button with the class of button because you didn't post any HTML but know that isn't good practice, it's redundant and confusing.

Give all the elements that you want to have a hover effect an encompassing class like `.hover` and the specific class of `.blue` or `.red` as applicable to the color you want.

```
.hover {
  background: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.blue {
    background: #337AB7;
}
.green {
    background: #008000;
}
.red {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Yes - you are absolutely right - I put a "." in front of the button:hover 
Sorry for not posting the HTML
And thanks for the tips with the buttons :)